# How to Select a Single Option Value Programmatically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using a "Select All" in my select list to clear any other selected options and ONLY select the "All" option. I can clear out all of the selected options, but I can't select the "All" option.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <mat-label>Select Program(s)</mat-label>
   <mat-select #myprograms  [formControl]="myprgrmFormControl" multiple [(ngModel)]="criteria.Program_ID" >
       <mat-option (click)="toggleAllSelection()" value="ALL" >All</mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let row of ProgramDropdown"  [value]="row.Program_ID" >
            {{row.Program_Name}} </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my ts file:

```
import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material/core';

myprgrmFormControl = new FormControl();
allSelected = false;
@ViewChild('myprograms') ProgSel: MatSelect;

toggleAllSelection() {
    this.allSelected = !this.allSelected;  // to control select-unselect    
    if (this.allSelected) {
       this.ProgSel.options.forEach( (item : MatOption) => item.deselect());
       //I changed the above from a select to a deselect since there are too many items in the list. 
       //The idea is that I clear all of the values, select "All" and will pass that value around
      in my code.
     } else {
       this.ProgSel.options.forEach( (item : MatOption) => {item.deselect()});
     }
}
```

How can a select the "All" option in the ts file?

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to accomplish this:

1. Since you are using objects as your `mat-option`, use a `compareWith` function in your `mat-select`, updated your `[(ngModel)]` and `mat-option` `[value]` binding to the object level.
2. Define an `allOption` that has a structure that will be evaluated correctly by your new `compareWith` function.
3. Programatically `setValue()` on `myprgrmFormControl` to an array with the new `allOption`. Update your `value` binding:  `[value]="allOption"`

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <mat-label>Select Program(s)</mat-label>
   <mat-select #myprograms  [formControl]="myprgrmFormControl" multiple [(ngModel)]="criteria" [compareWith]="selectCompare">
       <mat-option (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="allOption" >All</mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let row of ProgramDropdown"  [value]="row" >
            {{row.Program_Name}} </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
  allOption = { Program_ID: 'ALL', Program_Name: 'ALL' };

  toggleAllSelection() {
    this.allSelected = !this.allSelected; // to control select-unselect
    if (this.allSelected) {
      this.ProgSel.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => item.deselect());
      this.myprgrmFormControl.setValue([this.allOption]);
    } else {
      this.ProgSel.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => {
        item.deselect();
      });
    }
  }

  selectCompare(item1: SelectType, item2: SelectType) {
    return item1.Program_ID === item2.Program_ID;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqu7nc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html